# Reading small QR Code from a image using JSQR

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I'm using [JSQR](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR) library in ReactJS project to read QR code from image (jpg/png). Everything works fine but when QR code size is slightly small (not much, check the attached image), it fails several times.

[image: Qr Code Image]

**If I upload only cropped area of QR code, it reads it.**

*Current work flow of website:* It takes QR code image and convert it into `ImageData` using canvas and then pass that `ImageData` along with dimensions to JSQR (`const code = jsQR(imageData, width, height);`).

**How I can improve it? Is their any way to auto-detect QR code location in image to improve scanning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I'm posting it here for anyone facing similar issue.

It worked with a fork of jsQR libray `jsQR-es6` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsqr-es6)). I think its a improved version of jsQR with es6 support.